# Function initialisation

Tags: java

Is it necessary to always initialise the result variable in the function

For example

```
Public class Calculator

result=addition(a,b);

Public static int addition(int a, int b)
int result;
result =a+b;
return result;
```

Comment: Please don't just dump unformatted pseudo-code in a question. Write *real* code so we can easily tell what you mean.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm new to the app and was trying to figure how to get the code syntaxs right. Although I can assure it's not pseudo code and I did write this to understand functions better.

Comment: @Patrick: You removed the call to the method, which I suspect is important in understanding the OP's question.

Comment: "Although I can assure it's not pseudo code" - well the code you've posted certainly isn't valid Java. If you've written real sample code, why didn't you post it? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: @JonSkeet I thought it didn't matter, since it wasn't attached to anything. I assumed that was an entirely separate section of code, and the reuse of the variable name "result" was purely coincidental. Whoops.

Comment: @PatrickCollins: It's definitely a poorly-written example, but I *suspect* it matters, based solely on the user's comment on my answer.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to have a result *variable* at all. You need to make sure that every possible way that execution can reach the end of your function (without just throwing an exception) means you get to a return statement, and every return statement has an appropriate express to evaluate, but that doesn't mean you need a separate variable. Your example could be written as:

```
public static int addition(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

If you *do* use a variable, you'll need to make sure it's definitely assigned before you can read from it, including in a `return` statement. For example, this won't work because `result` hasn't been definitely assigned:

```
public static int addition(int a, int b) {
    int result;
    if (a < b) {
        result = a + b;
    }
    return result; // Invalid! result may not have a value
}
```

Where possible, it's generally a good idea to initialize a variable at the point of declaration. So if I were writing this code and wanted a `result` variable, I'd have:

```
public static int addition(int a, int b) {
    int result = a + b;
    return result;
}
```

Now, looking at your sample code again, you've got another variable used when you call the method:

```
result=addition(a,b);
```

It's not clear where that variable would be declared (which is one reason to avoid just posting pseudo-code in questions) but it's completely separate from the `result` variable in `addition`, which is *local* to the `addition` method. The two variables happen to have the same name, but they're otherwise unrelated. For example, you could easily have:

```
int sum = addition(a, b);
```

or call another method with the result instead of assigning it to a variable:

```
System.out.println(addition(a, b));
```

Or you could just ignore it entirely:

```
addtion(a, b); // Valid, but pointless unless there are side-effects
```

Comment: I'm sorry but if I don't have a variable what will the function return the value to? Do the functions not have to be told where to return the value?

Comment: @user3743672: The `result` variable declared in the method is irrelevant to the outside world anyway - it's up to whatever *calls* the method to store the return value if it wants it.

Comment: @user3743672: See my edit to the end of my answer for a bit more information.

Comment: And that's where the value will be returned to: the caller/client of the method.